# Enable curl at runtime in php

Tags: php, curl

I know we can enable curl extension by removing semicolon in php.ini

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

but i need to enable it using set_ini()
Could anybody tell me how to enable cURL in PHP using set_ini ?

Comment: since  modules are loaded during PHP startup  there is no way to do this at run time,

Answer (score 0):

Try [`dl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

```
dl('php_curl.dll');
```

You'll need to set [`enable_dl`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl) to use this function

Note that `dl` doesn't work with some versions of php 5.3